# React forum submit when pressing enter in textarea

Tags: html, reactjs

A am making this forum type app and to create a post you go through a form with a textarea; I want to support Markdown. So to do that you kind of need to support new line functionality. When I press the enter key this error occurs:

[image: Image off error in devtools]

This is the code

```
export default class CreatePost extends Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false,
    Title: '',
    Author: '',
    Body: '',
  };

  updateState = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  createPost = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.Body !== '') {
      this.props.createPost(this.state);
    }

    this.setState({ Title: '', Author: '', Body: '', redirect: true });
  };

  onEnterPress = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect push to='/' />;
    }
    return (
      <div className='createPost'>
        <h1>Create Your Post!</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.createPost}>
          <label className='input'>
            Title:{' '}
            <input
              type='text'
              name='Title'
              value={this.state.Title}
              onChange={this.updateState}
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className='input'>
            Author:{' '}
            <input
              type='text'
              name='Author'
              value={this.state.Author}
              onChange={this.updateState}
              required
            />
          </label>
          <textarea
            name='Body'
            className='body'
            value={this.state.Body}
            onKeyDown={this.onEnterPress}
            onChange={this.updateState}
          ></textarea>
          <input type='submit' value='Submit' className='submitBTN' />
        </form>
        <Link className='home' to='/'>
          Go Home
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried the regular on press down function but It doesn't work.

### Update #1

I got it to work but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the onEnterPress to the form itself, because the form also listens to the key presses.

```
<form onSubmit={this.createPost} onKeyDown={onEnterPress}>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvzo09kL/1/).

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Same error. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: That definitly works, I added a fiddle. Something else must be wrong then.

Comment: This didn't work in my code. It didn't work in your fiddle either. I got e.keyCode === "Enter" to make it work but the error still occurred.

Comment: what browser are you using

Comment: I am using Edge chromium browser